# cont = cont++ не работает

Tags: java

Не работает выражение `cont = cont++`

Сам код:

```
public class ForDemo {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        int cont;

        for (cont = 0; cont < 5; cont = cont++){
            System.out.println("Значение счетчика:" + cont);
        }

        System.out.println("Готово");
    }
}
```

Должно выводить:

```
> Значение счетчика:0
> Значение счетчика:1
> Значение счетчика:2
> Значение счетчика:3
> Значение счетчика:4
> Готово
```

Так выводит только при выражении `cont = cont + 1`
При двух плюсах уходит в бесконечность:

```
Значение счетчика:0
Значение счетчика:0
Значение счетчика:0
Значение счетчика:0
Значение счетчика:0
Значение счетчика:0
```

Comment: Правильно уходит. Читайте что такое постинкремент.

Answer (score 11):

Давай сначала. У тебя имеется постинкремент `myValue++`. В таком случае состояние объекта (переменной) должно измениться, но при этом возвращено предыдущее состояние. Поэтому происходит три операции:

- сохранение текущего значения во временную переменную (`int temp = myValue`)
- инкремент (`++myValue`)
- возвращение сохраненного состояния (`return temp`)

то есть схематично:

```
operator++(int) {
    int temp = myValue;
    myValue = myValue + 1;
    return temp;
}
```

Таким образом происходят действия и с переменной `cont`. А так как своё сохранённое состояние `temp` в итоге возвращается в ту же переменную, то, как результат, в нее **всегда** записывается ноль. В конце каждой итерации `cont` равен нулю, условие цикла всегда `0 < 5` и получается бесконечный цикл.

---

Как итог: нужно писать либо просто `cont++` либо просто `++cont` либо  `cont = cont + 1`.

Просто `cont++` сработает потому, что оператор отработает, переменная увеличится, а `return temp` будет делать некуда. Грубо говоря. И всё сработает как надо.

---

Ну или быть немного извращенцем и написать `cont = ++cont`, т.к. преинкремент **вначале** увеличивает значение на 1 и потом возвращает.

Comment: Хм,  что значит "правый cont" и "левый cont"? "cont" - он один. Я думал, порядок действий несколько другой. Все манипуляции с правой частью заканчиваются до выполнения оператора присваивания. То, что возвращается и присваивается левой части, равно доинкрементному значению "cont".

Comment: @Igor мне стоит написать так: `x = y++;` =>

`int tmp = y;
y = y + 1;
x = tmp;` ?

Comment: да, и: `cont = cont++;` => `int tmp = cont; cont = cont + 1; cont = tmp;`

Comment: @Igor так лучше?

Comment: Спасибо, моя картина мира снова непротиворечива :).