# возвращает ту же самую переменную

Tags: c#

сделал метод, который принимал переменную и возвращал на 1 больше, но почему то он возвращает ту же переменную

```
class HelloWorld {
    static double plus(double a){
        return a++;
    }
  static void Main() {
    double a = 2;
    Console.WriteLine(a);
    a = plus(a);
    Console.WriteLine(a);
  }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1355154/191482   ....   https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/708057/191482

Comment: не ПЕРЕМЕННУЮ, а ЗНАЧЕНИЕ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`++a` - сначала выполняется инкремент, а потом уже берется результат, `a++` - сначала берется результат, а потом выполняется инкремент. Если вы сделаете `++a`, то он вернет значение на 1 больше